# jQueryUI: handle hover over a non-droppable element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I can use `over` event of a `Droppable` to fire when `Draggable` is dragged over it.

But is there a nice way of handling similarly a `Draggable` being dragged over a non-Droppable element?

Comment: Not consistently and without significant effort. A common workaround is to just make the target `droppable`, and ban it from actually accepting any drops.

Comment: @blgt: Thanks, this actually worked for me. If you want to expand your comment to make it full answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll just post my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents us to make an element Droppable without actually defining drop function:

```
$('.drag-over-me').droppable(
  accept: '.some-draggable',
  over: (event, ui) ->
    # Do something...
)
```

Note that if Draggable is dropped onto it you (most probably) want to revert:

```
$('.some-draggable').draggable(
  revert: ( (droppable) ->
    droppable.hasClass('.drag-over-me')
  )
)
```